# How do I do a Simple Redirect in Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts, struts1

I have been searching web for hours, and I can't find answer to a simple question in Struts 2.  Basically, I have the following action in Struts 1 which is a simple forward, and I want to reproduce the same in Struts 2:

```
<action path="/az/api/v22/my-tenants" forward="/components/c/apis/v22/my-tenants.jsp">
      </action>
```

I could write an action class to do this, but I think Struts2 has to have some way of doing this without having to write an action class since it is is a simple redirection.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

Create *actionless* result in the `struts.xml`

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<package name="v22" namespace="/az/api/v22" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="my-tenants">
        <result>/components/c/apis/v22/my-tenants.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

---

This configuration defines a package with namespace `/az/api/v22` and action name `my-tenants`. So if you use path `/az/api/v22/my-tenants` it will be mapped to the action config above, because default action mapper is using namespace and action name together to get the action config.

There's no `class` attribute in the action tag, and it uses class `ActionSupport` instead. This class is configured by default in `struts-default` package.

In the result it's enough to define the location of the JSP, because struts2 defaults are using a dispatcher that forwards to JSP, and it's using `"success"` result code by default in the result config which is returned by default by `ActionSupport` class.

Comment: Can be this done without using the namespace attribute of the package.  The problem is that a  package in Struts2 has already been created that these calls are going to be part of it.  So, I don't have control over the package's namespace.

Comment: Without namespace attribute you are missing a part that should be added before the action name.