# In Apache Struts, how can I redirect to an external URL without writing an Action class?

Tags: redirect, struts2, struts, endpoint, actionresult

In my Struts application, I need to create an endpoint (URL) which simply tells the user's browser to redirect to an external URL.

It looks like this can be done by creating a new Action class and defining a new `<result type='redirect'>` result, but that seems like overkill.  I don't need an Action class to do any kind of processing on my end, just a simple redirect.

Is there a way I can set up an endpoint simply with a line or two in a configuration file?

Comment: What do you mean by set up an endpoint? Struts configuration is used to *map* specific endpoints that is requested by the browser client and then find the corresponding action config.

Comment: An endpoint meaning a URL defined by me.  Usually I use the term "endpoint" to mean the URL without the server/domain name.  So I want to know if I can add a line to `struts.xml` to map something like "/redirect_to_outside_website", not to an Action class, but directly to an outside URL.

Comment: If you don't want to use the existing mechanism, create one--if it's your app that's being hit it's your app that has to send the redirect. You can either do it using what's provided, or do it another way--the req wouldn't even need to get to the app.

Comment: Well, that's my question: is there something that's provided? Some kind of shortcut notation that can go in struts.xml for a redirect?

Comment: @workerjoe Without a server/domain name your URI doesn't be an *endpoint*. Also Struts `redirect` result alows you to use internal and external URLs as well. If you made a dig into Struts configuration a bit then you could find an information how endpoints are created and served by the config-browser plugin. However the result config is a placeholder for any endpoint, but you can't execute it directly, i.e. without the action invocation. It's not clear where do you want to add a `redirect` result in `struts.xml`. You should add it to the question.

Comment: If I knew the syntax, I wouldn't have asked the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the endpoint using an action configuration and without the `Action` class. Then add a `redirect` result type. You can use it with any package that extends a `struts-default`.

```xml
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="redirect_to_outside_website/*">
        <result type="redirect">{1}</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

---

You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371149/573032).

---

To use slashes in action name  you should use these constants

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

---

The example above can redirect to any URL using a wildcard mapper (which is a default mapper in Struts 2). If you need to fix the URL in the configuration file, then you can place a fixed URL directly to the `<result>` tag.

```xml
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="redirect_to_outside_website">
        <result type="redirect">https://server_domain/my_fixed_location</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  I discovered that I can drop the `/*` and hard-code a destination in the `result` element (where you have `{1}`) if I want to simply redirect to a fixed URL.  Do you want to add that to the answer?

Comment: Sure, just added.